# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I am trying to develop a simple web application with netbeans and MySQL. I have data in mysql and want to show them in web browser. I get the following error in the web page when I running the project.

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: 
    SELECT subject_id, name FROM Subject
: Table/View 'SUBJECT' does not exist.
root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'SUBJECT' does not exist.
root cause

org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Table/View 'SUBJECT' does not exist.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.

Answer (score -1):

Try making the table name uppercase.

```
SELECT subject_id, name FROM SUBJECT
```

Please have a look at the following post describing [**Identifier Case Sensitivity**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)